# Nodejs Connection to HTML

Tags: sql-server, node.js, mean-stack, node-modules

I am Getting an HTML ERROR, Trying to render a sql db to the index page with setting up a connection. The table name is employee and no error while running the app on the terminal but an error page on the html link.

```
var express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();

    /* GET home page. */
    router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
      GetData(function (recordSet) {
          res.render('index', {product: recordSet})
          console.log(recordSet);
      });
    });

    function GetData(callBack){
      var sql = require('mssql');
      var Config = {
        user: 'Gurpanth\\Gurpanth',
          password: '',
          database:'NodeJSDb',
          server:'GURPANTH'
      };
      var conn = new sql.ConnectionPool(Config,function (err) {
         //If any error
         var request = new sql.Request(conn);
         request.query('Select * from  products', function(err, recordSet){
           callBack(recordSet);
         });
      });
    }

    module.exports = router;
```

---

INDEX.EJS

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
      </head>
      <body>
      <table>
      <tbody>

        <td><%=productName%></td>

      </tbody>
      </table>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: what is the error on html link?

Comment: C:\Users\Gurpanth\WebstormProjects\Database\views\index.ejs:10 8| <tbody> 9| >> 10| <td><%=product.productName%></td> 11| 12| </tbody> 13| </table> Cannot read property 'productName' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the variable product: `res.render('index', {product: recordSet})`
but in the ejs file you are using productName `<td><%=productName%></td>`

Change both to the same